# Syntax error with variable containing quotes

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, quoting, ssh-config

I have a bunch of Linux machines behind 2 gateways. To connect to set one I do

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh gateway1 nc %h %p" machines_behind_1
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh gateway2 nc --proxy %h %p --proxy-type socks4" machines_behind_2
```

To simplify this process, I thought I would create a environment variable to hold the proxycommand and simply use that. So I did

```
export PGWA='-o ProxyCommand="ssh gateway1 nc %h %p"'
export PGWB='-o ProxyCommand="ssh gateway2 nc --proxy %h %p --proxy-type socks4"'
```

Then, depending on the machine I want to connect, I would do

```
ssh $PGWA machine_behind_1
ssh $PGWB machine_behind_2
```

But I get this error -

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Any idea why?

I can't use any ssh_config tricks, because I don't know the hostnames ahead of time. I might create a new VM behind gateway1 , and I will need to use the first proxy command.

The only thing I can think of is create a new alias, a function or a shell script which basically does `ssh -o foo $@` and use that instead. But then, I need to remember to create an alias/shell script or function for scp as well, which too I use regularly. I would rather be able to do it automatically.

I kinda hoped I could do something like `ssh gw1-host` and do some manipulation inside the config file to convert it to `ssh -o foo host` through the first gateway, but that kind of regex manipulation is not allowed inside the ssh_config.

Any way I can achieve what I want without individual ssh / scp alias/script/function?

EDIT: I had made a mistake with the quoting when I copy-pasted the environment variable into stack exchange here.

Comment: Did you really mean to have unbalanced quotes in your examples?  Is that your problem?

Comment: Wow that was pretty stupid of me. I do have single quotes at the beginning and end, and double quotes within the ProxyCommand="" variable.

Comment: When in doubt, ***"quote everything"***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `$PGWA` without quotes, this splits the value of `PGWA` at whitespace¹. Quote characters have no special meaning there, so you end up with the words `-o`, `ProxyCommand="ssh`, `gateway1`, `nc`, `%h` and `%p"`.

See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for more explanations.

A variable expansion outside of double quotes is almost always a mistake. It's always a mistake unless you know why you need to leave the double quotes off.

What you need to do is to pass two arguments to the SSH command: `-o` and `ProxyCommand=ssh gateway2 nc --proxy %h %p --proxy-type socks4`.

In zsh, you could just set `PGWA` to an array:

```
PGWA=(-o 'ProxyCommand=ssh gateway2 nc --proxy %h %p --proxy-type socks4')
ssh $PGWA …
```

In other shells such as bash and ksh, this requires more typing, because of their design misfeature that unquoted variable expansions undergo splitting and because of their explicit syntax for arrays:

```
PGWA=(-o 'ProxyCommand=ssh gateway2 nc --proxy %h %p --proxy-type socks4')
ssh "${PGWA[@]}" …
```

A method that would work in any sh-like shell and wouldn't require much typing would be to define functions.

```
pgwa () {
  typeset c="$1"; shift
  "$c" -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh gateway2 nc --proxy %h %p --proxy-type socks4' "$@"
}
pgwa ssh …
```

But I think the best solution would be to put all of these definitions in your `.ssh/config` where they belong. This way you wouldn't need any shell tricks and the configurations would work in other programs (rsync, sshfs, GUI file transfer programs, etc.). If you add a new VM behind gateway1, either add an entry to `.ssh/config` or use `ssh -o HostName=new-vm something-behind-gateway1 …`

¹  <sub>Plus other things that don't matter here.</sub>

Comment: Wow thank you. That was a pretty awesome explanation and links. The array technique works, but I think I will stick to functions ..

Comment: @HariSundararajan any reason for not using the `.ssh/config` file ?